# weird reflection on rendered images/videos

Tags: rendering

so like the title says, every time a render something and the object reflects the light, that light spot on the objet looks like really bad. i uploaded an image , the object has no modifiers. its only a plane with glass bsdf  so you can understand what is my problem. thanks for any help[image]

Comment: What are you using for a lamp? Point? Spot? Area? Plane with emission material?

Comment: any kind of lightsource does the same. spot, lamp, hdr, anything that reflects from it makes this bad looking reflection when rendered

Comment: Please upload your blend file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and edit the question to paste the link so others can inspect your setup and try and spot the problem.